# Required fields in ReleaseStartMetadata contract when creating a new VSTS release via the rest api

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to write a powershell script to create and start a new Release based on an existing release definition.  I'm having trouble building the ReleaseStartMetadata object that is required as the body of the POST request.  The documentation [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/contracts#ReleaseStartMetadata), [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/contracts#ArtifactMetadata), and [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/contracts#BuildVersion), does not say anything about which fields are required and which are optional, and in some cases (BuildVersion) gives no explanation at all about what the fields mean and where to find the values to populate them.

The release definition I'm using depends on two sets of artifacts.  One is a build artifact and one is a source artifact.  The release definition is configured to default to the latest artifact version for both, but I can't find any way via the rest api to specify to just use the default (latest) artifacts.  So I'm assuming I need to explicitly specify which artifact versions to use.  All the examples I've found online show how to create a release using a build artifact, but I can find no examples of using a source artifact.  I'm guessing the "sourceVersion" field on the BuildVersion contract should be the changeset id, but I have no idea where to find values to specify for "sourceBranch", "sourceRepositoryId", and "sourceRepositoryType".

Here's the script I have so far:

```
$authinfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("my@email.com:blahblahtokenvalueblahblahblah"))
$headers = @{}
$headers.Add('Authorization', ("Basic {0}" -f $authinfo))
$headers.Add('Content-Type', 'application/json')

$uri = 'https://my-account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0&definitions=16'
$buildsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
$build = $buildsResponse | Select -Expand value | Sort -Property id | Select -Last 1
$buildId = $build | Select -Expand id
$buildNumber = $build | Select -Expand buildNumber
Write-Host "Found latest build.  BuildId: $buildId, BuildNumber: $buildNumber"

$uri = 'https://my-account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_apis/tfvc/changesets?api-version=1.0&searchCriteria.itemPath=$/MyProject'
$changesetsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
$changeset = $changesetsResponse | Select -Expand value | Sort -Property changesetId | Select -Last 1
$changesetId = $changeset | Select -Expand changesetId
Write-Host "Found latest changeset.  ChangesetId: $changesetId"

$uri = 'https://my-account.vsrm.visualstudio.com/MyProject/_apis/release/releases?api-version=4.0-preview.4'
$body = @{
    definitionId = 3
    description = 'Testing release via Rest API'
    isDraft = $FALSE
    reason = 'none'
    manualEnvironments = $NULL
    artifacts = @(
        @{
            alias = 'My Build Artifact'
            instanceReference = @{
                id = "$buildId"
                name = $buildNumber
            }
        },
        @{
            alias = 'My Source Artifact'
            instanceReference = @{
                sourceBranch = "Dev"
                sourceRepositoryId = $NULL
                sourceRepositoryType = $NULL
                sourceVersion = "$changesetId"
            }
        }
    )
    properties = $NULL
}
$createResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body
$releaseId = $createResponse | Select id
Write-Host "Release Created: $releaseId"
```

When I run this, the first two requests work ok, and I get the expected values, but the POST request fails with this exception:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
    "$id":"1",
    "innerException":null,
    "message":"VS402903: The specified value is not convertible to type ReleaseStartMetadata. Make sure it is convertible to type eleaseStartMetadata and try again.",
    "typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Data.Exceptions.InvalidRequestException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement2.Data",
    "typeKey":"InvalidRequestException",
    "errorCode":0,
    "eventId":3000
}
At C:\dev\PShell\MyScript.ps1:49 char:19
+ ... eResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $uri -Headers $head ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Even if I fill in some bogus values for sourceRepositoryId and sourceRepository type, I get the same error.  So now I'm left with two questions:

1. Where do I find values to populate all the source* fields on the BuildVersion contract for a source artifact?
2. What else is wrong with my data structure preventing it from properly parsing as a ReleaseStartMetadata object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, shortly after I posted the question, I stumbled upon an article that eventually lead me to the answers I needed.

For question 1, the answer is the only actual required field in the BuildVersion contract is "id".

- For build artifacts, this should be the buildId.
- For TFVC source artifacts, this should be the changesetId.
- And as starian chen-MSFT mentioned in his answer, for Git source artifacts this should be the commit id.

For question 2, the piece I was missing was converting my @-notation object to json by appending " | ConvertTo-Json 100" to the $body definition.

As a little additional bonus info, if anyone else is confused about what "Sets list of environments to manual as condition." means (from the documentation of the ReleaseStartMetadata contract), if your release definition is configured for new releases to start automatically on any of its environments, you can disable the automatic start when creating a release by listing those environments in the manualEnvironments field.  I had to do this to prevent my new release (intended for our Automation testing environment) from automatically starting to deploy to the Development environment.

So my final, working $body definition looks like this:

```
$body = @{
    definitionId = 3
    description = 'Testing release via Rest API'
    isDraft = $FALSE
    reason = 'none'
    manualEnvironments = @('Development')
    artifacts = @(
        @{
            alias = 'My Build Artifact'
            instanceReference = @{
                id = "$buildId"
            }
        },
        @{
            alias = 'My Source Artifact'
            instanceReference = @{
                id = "$changesetId"
            }
        }
    )
    properties = $NULL
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Git source as artifact, then the instanceReference id is the commit id, but you are using TFVC REST API, so it is incorrect.

Sample:

```
{
"definitionId":1,
"isDraft":false,
"description":"",
"manualEnvironments":[],
"artifacts":
[
{
"alias":"Asp.netVnext",
"instanceReference":
{
"id":"6459",
"name":"null"
}
},
{
"alias":"WebAPI",
"instanceReference":{
"id":"26e0df34d57fc68ce1706f230eee03c4166d24d0",
"name":"null",
"sourceBranch":"dev"
}
}
]
}
```

If you are using TFVC source as artifact, then instanceReference id is the changeset id, but there aren’t sourceBranch, sourcerepositoryId parameters/keys, just id and name.

Sample:

```
{
"definitionId":1
,"isDraft":false,
"description":"",
"manualEnvironments":[],
"artifacts":[
{
"alias":"ScrumStarain2",
"instanceReference":{
"id":"1705",
"name":"Changeset 1705"
}
}
]}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah this matches what I have found.